# Wi-Fi does not work after starting OpenVPN client

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, internet, openvpn

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and for a few days now, my computer has had problems connecting to various Wi-Fi networks. Currently, it shows that it is connected to my home network, and for a minute after connecting, it worked fine, but now it doesn't load the pages anymore. Additional information:

- I installed a VPN certificate a few days ago with `systemctl enable "openvpn-client@{hostname}.service"` and `systemctl start "openvpn-client@{hostname}.service"`
- When the Wi-fi is turned off, the settings window says "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found"

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved for now by disabling the OpenVPN client with `systemctl stop openvpn-client@{hostname}.service`.